# Enhanced collections methods on an Iterator

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to use the enhanced Collections methods that Groovy provides, like **findAll** and **Collect** with an iterator (of class *java.util.Iterator*) ?

Comment: Could you elaborate further on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a Java method that returns an Iterator of items, and I was using the findAll to filter, and the collect to process those items, but it didn't seem to work. Then I realized I was operating on an Iterator object instead of a Collection. So what I did was to convert the Iterator into a Collection with an utility class from Apache Commons Collections. But I though it was strange it didn't support iterators, so I'm asking this question because maybe I'm not using them in the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the enhanced methods (including `findAll` and `collect`) *do* work with iterators.  You can test it out in the console:

```
assert [1,2,3].iterator().findAll{ it % 2 } == [1,3]
assert [1,2,3].iterator().collect{ it * 2 } == [2,4,6]
```

Check out [DefaultGroovyMethods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) for a list of the extra methods groovy provides.  In general, whenever your class is an instance of the first arg's type, that method applies to your class.  In the case of `collect` and `findAll`, iterator uses the `Object` version.  Others, like `collectMany` have an iterator specific version.